# Queues for every thread in thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, task-queue, executor

As far I know, thread pools (java.util.concurrent.Executor class) provide a queue of tasks for all threads in a pool. So I don't really know, which thread will execute my task. But I need to have queues of tasks assigned to every thread. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you care which thread executes one particular task as long as the job gets done eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only certain threads to execute certain tasks you a standard Threadpool will not fit.
But you can use multiple Threadpools with only one thread in each to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your program so you don't need to know what thread executes a task.  They are just anonymous worker threads.

However, if you really want to know anyway you can create a single threaded ExecutorService for each thread you want and then you will know which thread will execute a task.

Comment: You right, but in my program all input separated between workers in special order, that's why when I get new input I decide which worker will execute it, and then I put this input into his thread. I see, that it's really not a good idea. I'll try to avoid this trap. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @notnavol I would be careful about splitting input in this way.  If you cut it up too finely you can end up with a solution where the overhead is 10x the work you are performing (or even much more) This can make a multi-threaded solutions much, much slower than a single thread solution.